# How to save each item in an array as a document using mongoose ? If any document matches item in array, it should not be created

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a categorySchema in mongoose like so :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const categorySchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    }
},{timestamps:true});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Category',categorySchema);
```

I will get an array from request like so :

```
const categories = ['phones','computer','bikes','cars'];
```

I already have bikes and cars in my categories collection. I can iterate through each item in the array and save it as a document. But I need each document to be unique. No two documents with same name (Obviously). I guess I can find the existing documents using `$in` in the find query and remove each documents by iterating through the array of documents I get after that I can iterate through the array I got from the request and save each item as new documents. But I wanted to know if there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: Use unique index by setting `unique:true` as suggested by Janardan (Recommended). For any reason, you can't do that, you can always query a document for distinct values `db.category.distinct( "name" )` which will give you results as you need, no repeated name.

Comment: Thanks for the Idea. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your schema like this:

```
const categorySchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required:true,
        unique: true
    }
},{timestamps:true});
```

Comment: Yep converted it !